# Wake effect in games and Unity

Tags: unity, water, effect, fluid-dynamics

I was curious about how wake effects are added in video games. Do most games use blender to mimic this effect and is it dynamic or does it have any drawbacks?

Has anyone ever tried making it in Unity and have it change dynamically? I know this exists in Unreal's Fluid Flux plug-in but isn't that graphically demanding?

Would love to hear the community's opinions and thoughts on this as I'm currently trying to understand the concept and its implementation.

Comment: This looks like it should be an edit to [your previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/208257/39518), not a new question post. I linked you to examples and tutorials about implementing this kind of effect in Unity. What have you tried based on your research thus far?

Comment: I did look at a few ways of how this is has been done so far and most results made use of blender like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14SNmHvVBio. However, I have absolutely no experience with using Blender and I wanted to do something entirely in Unity.

Comment: Some other implementations I came across make use of particle effects and trail renderers (including one asset in the unity store for URP) but I wanted to add some more details to it such as the vortex street one observes on the trail of a boat and make a single implementation across various fluids and objects. I am currently trying to make my own implementation using foam, particles, deformers and trail in Unity but I'm looking for more clues to make it dynamic.

Comment: I also wanted to create a mesh skirt around the object as that will help me divide the visual aspects of the wake based on the boundary layer regions but again that will be specific to one particular object.

Comment: Then [refine your search to remove Blender hits and search only for how folks have done it in Unity](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+water+%22wake%22+-blender&ia=web).